# Rsync: "chown failed: permission denied (13)"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, rsync, mount

I run a rsync task every midnight using the following command:

```
rsync -ahzP --stats --update --delete-before --delete-excluded --exclude "*.log" --exclude temp /mnt/raid/ /mnt/backups > /root/ext_backup.log 2>&1
```

> */mnt/backups* is a NFS mount.

The backup process runs smoothly for about half an hour, then I get the following error:

```
rsync: [receiver] write failed on "/my/file": Input/output error (5)
rsync: [receiver] chown "/my/file" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(378) [receiver=3.2.3]

rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: the output is self explanatory on what's wrong. further info will require more details on the file

Comment: @Alex what further info do you need?

Comment: According to the error message, `rsync` doesn't have permission to change the owner (`chown`) of the file. This is probably due to how the NFS mount permissions are set up and/or what user `rsync` is running as.

Comment: @GordonDavisson rsync is running as root, and I allowed "Everyone" to r/w to the directory (NFS share from Windows Server 2022).

Comment: @alex3025 you need `no_root_squash` to keep root mapping on the server. Otherwise root will be mapped to nobody and chown will fail.

Comment: @kofemann so I need to allow `no_root_squash` on my NFS server or client?

Comment: This is en export option in the server

Comment: @kofemann I can't find where enable that option in Windows Server.

Comment: No idea how it done under windows. May be this links will help https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/nfs-identity-mapping-in-windows-server-2012/ba-p/424602

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem it was necessary to check the "Allow root access" checkbox.

[image]